# iPhone - UIImagePickerController shows a white screen sometimes

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using a shared instance of UIImagePickerController in my application. I am using the Camera Roll as the image source.

Sometimes when the image picker opens, instead of seeing the photos gallery, I am able to see only a blank white screen. This issue is not reproducible every time and happens only some of the times.

Has someone else faced this issue? Is it the memory usage? I checked the app with Instruments while testing on the device but memory doesn't seem to be the issue.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what version of the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by a memory issue. I created a shared instance of UIImagePickerController and used it throughout the app.